# load Boston dataset with pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm having an issue loading the Boston dataset with pandas. It seems like it't not recognizing the continuing/newlines. What am I missing?
**python 3.9.0**
**pandas 1.3.5**

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer="http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/boston", sep="  ", skiprows=21)
```

[image]

Comment: what's the error trace?

Comment: You might try [Boston corrected](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/boston_corrected.txt) which has corrected data and no line wraps. It does add latitude and longitude though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a good way to read in a table which has it's rows on multiple lines. Here's an approach that reads in the table, converts it to a single list of values, drops the nulls, and reshapes to have a new table with the correct number of columns

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(
    filepath_or_buffer="http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/boston",
    delim_whitespace=True,
    skiprows=21,
    header=None,
)

columns = [
    'CRIM',
    'ZN',
    'INDUS',
    'CHAS',
    'NOX',
    'RM',
    'AGE',
    'DIS',
    'RAD',
    'TAX',
    'PTRATIO',
    'B',
    'LSTAT',
    'MEDV',
]

#Flatten all the values into a single long list and remove the nulls
values_w_nulls = df.values.flatten()
all_values = values_w_nulls[~np.isnan(values_w_nulls)]

#Reshape the values to have 14 columns and make a new df out of them
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = all_values.reshape(-1, len(columns)),
    columns = columns,
)

df
```